# Unable to load the requested file: header.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-hmvc

I am Following this link [converting-html-template-to-codeigniter](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/converting-html-template-to-codeigniter), but Some how it cant able to run header file. here Is my code

```
<?php    
$this->load->view($this->config->item('bootsshop_template_dir_public') . 'header');
$this->load->view($this->config->item('bootsshop_template_dir_public') . 'content');
$this->load->view($this->config->item('bootsshop_template_dir_public') . 'footer');
```

can some one help me ... Thanx

Here is my error window 
[image]

Comment: may be missing header.php file or mismatch file path

Comment: where is the location of header.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can load view file with file name only.No need to load full path.
like..
$this->load->view('header');

Answer (score 0):

Well for this work i have some best method which call layouts

**Number 1 :**
go to your **views** folder and create a new folder see the bellow image

[image]

**Number 2 :** add new php file name it **layout.php** and add this code in the **layout.php** file

```
<?php
$this->load->view('common/header');
$this->load->view($view_page);
$this->load->view('common/footer');
```

**Note :** the common is my folder name which is located in views folder

**Number 3 :** Now add the custom controller file inside core folder see in the image

[image]

And add the following code in this file

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
   protected $data;
   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
   }

   /*  Load the front end layout and set the ouput */
   public function render($layout)
   {
       $this->load->view('layouts/'.$layout, $this->data);
   }
}
```

**Number 4 :** Go to your controller file and extends your controller with this file see in the image

[image]

Now you able to load your views and pass data to views by the following code

```
public function index(){
    $this->data['view_page'] = 'index';
    $this->render('layout');
}
```

You can send data with method see the following function.

```
public function index(){
    $this->data['pass_your_data_var_here'] = $data;
    $this->data['view_page'] = 'index';
    $this->render('layout');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working for this too and search a lot, but I can't see any solution.
I tried this fix the problem my self and I figured out the code.
here's what I do in layout.php
I change

> bootsshop_template_dir_public

into

> ci_my_admin_template_dir_public

here is the whole code:

```
$this->load->view($this->config->item('ci_my_admin_template_dir_public') . 'header');
$this->load->view($this->config->item('ci_my_admin_template_dir_public') . 'content');
$this->load->view($this->config->item('ci_my_admin_template_dir_public') . 'footer');
```

Hope this will help you and other that facing the same problem with [kode-blog admin panel tutorial](https://kode-blog.io/converting-html-template-to-codeigniter).